# Calculating fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I've a fourier series with a period = $2\pi$ that is even.
f(t) =
\begin{cases}
0 \text{, when: } 0<t<\pi-2  \\
\pi \text{, when: } \pi-2<t<\pi
\end{cases}
The functions trigonometric fourier series equals:

$2 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\cos(kt)\cdot\frac{\sin(2k)}{k}$

What is the value of the series when $t = \pi-2$?

I tried to insert the value of t in the series and use Parevals formula and calculate the integral but I didn't manage to handle the integral. What should I do to calculate the sum of the series?

Comment: You don't need to use the series. What do you know about the value of a fourier series at a point of discontinuity of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to derive a 'bonus sum' using Parseval's formula here - note that the function satisfies Dirichlet's conditions on the open interval $ (0,\pi) $ (prove this), and note that the function is discontinuous at $ t= \pi -2 $, and recall that the Fourier series converges to the average of the left and right limits at any point of discontinuity.

Comment: We haven't gone through Dirichlet's conditions so even if it might work I don't think I'm supposed to use it unfortunately :/
You don't happen to have another method to calculate this? :)

Comment: The value of a fourier series at a discontinuity (jump) is its average value.

Comment: Ah so it seems. Thanks for the fast Response Paul, and sorry for not responding to your first comment (was going to). :)

Comment: @user139094 - I guess if you haven't covered Dirichlet's conditions, stating what Paul said in your answer is fine

Comment: @Eweler - I've been teaching engineers too long:)